# Where are the errors located in the Azure portal GUI?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-git-deployment

## Where are the errors located in the Azure portal GUI?

### Abstract

I'm currently developing a **Flask** app, deploying it on **Azure**.
I've configured **CI/CD** with GitHub. Each push to the desired branch causes the thing to build.
There seems, **however**, to be a **problem** with this build that I need to **discover**.

Despite my great effort, **despite** reading a few pages of Azure **docs** and a few **answers** on this site, **I cannot seem to find the actual location that would show me the Azure build errors I want to see**.

### What have I tried

#### Log Analytics

I've configured Log Analytics. I can't remember its function, but it was necessary to enable some logging.

#### GUI

I've checked the Logs tab for my AppService. Although I've noticed a few errors, these look as unhelpful as this:
[image: Error in Logs in Azure AppService]
**If this is the most I would get, please note that in the comments.**

#### Log Streaming

I've started streaming logs in VS Code. These only tell me that `An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.`

#### Downloading logs from app's subdirectory

Although I cannot pin-point the exact article, there is a way of downloading logs from the app's endpoint. I did it, got two files and the most I would get is `ERROR - Container for *app name* site *app name* is unhealthy, Stopping site.`
**Again, if this is meaningful for a rudimentary Flask app deployed in CI/CD pipeline with no tampering in the settings of Azure, let me know.**

### Wrapping up

Are the samples shown valid, meaningful errors? If not, where can I find more information?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by configuring an app with CI/CD using GitHub and integrated successfully as shown below:

[image]

if we made any changes in the repository then it will trigger a workflow and build process takes places.

If there are any errors then we can look at those errors in the github repository only by navigating to the Actions-->click on build, there you can see the errors as shown below:

[image]

You can also review the application logs, either by [enabling diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) on app service to identify the cause or you can make use of application logs under (diagnose and solve problems--> availability and performance) from the portal under your web app.